# assertEquals not working as expected with Set in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm wondering if there is any clean way of comparing list or set of objects. I did a couple of experiments, failing in both:

```
    @Test
    fun `mytest`(){
        class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)

        assertEquals(
                setOf(Person("john", 33), Person("Peter", 88)),
                setOf(Person("john", 33), Person("Peter", 88)),
                "this test fails"
        )
    }
```

Also I tried with containsAll:

```
@Test
    fun `mytest`(){
        class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)


        val persons = setOf(Person("john", 33), Person("Peter", 88))
        assertTrue(
                persons.containsAll(setOf(Person("john", 33), Person("Peter", 88))),
                "This test also fails"
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected, because in a `class` without an `equals()` method, `assertEquals()` compares that they are the same instance, not object equality. This is the same for a "normal" Kotlin `class` as in a Java `class`.

In Kotlin, there's a simple solution: simply change make it a `data class` instead of just `class`, which automatically generates `equals()`/`hashCode()`, as well as `toString()` and some other useful things (see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)

```kotlin
@Test
fun `mytest`(){
    data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)

    assertEquals(
            "data classes are cool",
            setOf(Person("john", 33), Person("Peter", 88)),
            setOf(Person("john", 33), Person("Peter", 88))
    )
}
```

(I think `message` comes first in `assertEquals?`)

Or manually add an `equals()` method for cases where this doesn't work (but remember when you add `equals()`, you should also add a corresponding `hashCode()`)

Answer (score 4):

that is because `Person("john", 33)` is not equal to `Person("john", 33)` unless you mark the class as [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html): `data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)`

Comment: Or they could also override the `equals` method.

Comment: + `hashCode` method.